# Escaped char in Parsley does not extract escaped char

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following Parsley grammar:

```
# one char version of whitespace
wsc = ' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r'
escapedChar = '\\\\' anything

symbol = <(escapedChar | ~(',' | ';' | wsc) anything)+>
```

When I parse `\\,` with `.escapedChar()`, the string I obtain is `,`. However, when I parse `test\,` with `.symbol()`, the string I obtain is `test\,` instead of `test,`.

Comment: I would like to clarify that neither the `parsley` nor `parsley.js` tag fits my question. I am asking about a Python parsing library called [parsley](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Parsley).